# Changing the color of the lollipop... Does this serve any real purpose?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Screwing around in the software info I pressed Android Version 7 times. The lollipop showed up on my screen. I touched it and it changed colors. ( Yippee :P) But does this do anything other than that? ( ie Open a new exploit of something cool like that)

Comment: They're called [Easter eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_easter_eggs) More [here](http://www.askvg.com/hidden-secret-easter-eggs-and-daydreams-in-google-android-devices/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But if you long tap it, you can play a game similar to Flappy Bird.